# Linq to SQL Exists, GroupBy And Having

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have this SQL statement which works fine. I'm trying to convert this into a VB Linq to SQL statement without any luck. I'm stuck here. Can someone please help me with this?

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Product AS P
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT productid
    FROM Product_Promo AS PP
    WHERE P.productid = PP.productid
        AND P.Someid = 1003
        AND PP.ADate > getdate()
    GROUP BY productid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

My VB.Net attempt:

```
From p In Products
Where (From pp In Product_Promo
    Where pp.ADate > DateTime.Now
    Select pp.productid
    Group By productid
    Into Group
    Where Group.Count > 1)
    .Contains(p.ProductID)
Select p
Where p.Someid = 1003
```

Got It!

```
Products.Where(Function(p) (p.Product_Promo.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(pp) ((p.SomeID = 1003) AndAlso (pp.ADate> DateTime.Now))) > 1))
```

Thanks for the answers...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Evaldas,

I tried several examples looked similar to my problem. Unfortunately no success yet =/


`code`
    From p In Products
    Where (From pp In Product_Promo
    Where pp.ADate > DateTime.Now
    Select pp.productid 
    Group By productid Into Group 
    Where Group.Count > 1).Contains(p.ProductID)
    Select p
    Where p.Someid = 1003
`code`

Comment: A good question is in the details. Words like "stuck" or "no success" don't tell much.

Comment: Besides, queries like that point to mapping issues - you shouldn't have to join the two **entities**, there should be a relation between them. Product should have a `Promos` property and `Product_Promo` should have a `Product`